# GNU Parallel: set remote server run on 1 job with all CPU

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have jobs (multiprocessing python codes) that ideally take 4 CPUs to run on each remote machine.  In GNU parallel, how do I set up the arguments to make each remote server (assuming 4 cores) run one job at a time, using all its 4 cores on the same job (instead of using its 4 cores to run 4 job by default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run (25% of 4 cores) jobs in parallel with each 4 args:

```
-j 25% -N4
```

Comment: Will this utilize the full computing power of each core or 25% of each core ?